# Passing values to nested apex page for editing

Tags: salesforce

I have an apex page with custom extension. I am using pageblocktable to show all available records. Table has modify button, on click of button I am showing another nested apex page in a javascript dialog. Question is how to pass pageblocktable row values to nested page for editing purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can share same controller for both pages.

Page1:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Object__c"   extensions="MyController">
<apex:column headerValue="Action">
<apex:commandLink  action="{!goToPage2}" value="Edit" >
  <apex:param name="rowId" assignTo="{!rowId}" value="{!item.Component.Id}" />
</apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>
</apex:page>
```

Page2:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Object__c"   extensions="MyController">
{!objForPage2.Name}
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MyController{
public string rowId {get;set;}
Object__c objForPage2;
public Pagereference goToPage2(){
for(Object__c obj : objectList){
            if(obj.Id==rowId){
                objForPage2= obj;
            }
        } 
return Page.Page2;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Shimshon. What is "f" in objForPage2= f;? Should it be objForPage2.Id= obj.Id?

Comment: I fix it objForPage2= obj;

Comment: Here is my situation:
**Page 1:**
I have this command button in pageblocktable column
 `<apex:commandLink reRender="catTable"  title="Modify" action="editBuilding" >
<apex:param name="bIdModifyParam" value="{!item.id}" assignTo="{!selectedrowId}"/>
 </apex:commandLink>`

Comment: On click of button showing this dialog with javascript:

 `<div class="popupMain clearfix">
                <apex:include pageName="Page2"/>
               <!--  <apex:iframe src="/apex/Page2?id={!selectedRowId}"  id="theIframe"/>-->
</div>`

**Page 1 Controller extension:**

 `public PageReference editBuilding()
    {
      
      for(Facilities_FSR_Building__c obj : Rows){
                if(obj.Id==selectedrowId){
                    building.Id= obj.Id;
                }
            } 
       // return Page.Facilities_FSR_EditBuilding;
      return null;
    }`

Comment: **Page 2:**
`<apex:inputField value="{!Page2_StdController.Id}"/>`


When I click modify button, dialog does not open but shows message that "ID should begin with \", becuase selectedRowId is not being passed.

Comment: Hi, I followed your steps, but in page 2 I am getting error that "Unknown property 'Object__c.objForPage2'

Comment: this nead to be "public Object__c objForPage2{get;set;}"

Comment: I have it as property only.